# Sympy List All Symbolic Functions in Expression

Tags: sympy

I want to find a way to get the free symbolic functions in an expression. I know you can use atoms() and other functions, but they do not list the functions. More importantly, I need to know how many times a function appears in an expression (and if it is being exponentiated so I can account for how many times it is there)

Example:

```
t = Symbol('t',real=True)
x = Symbol('x',real=True)
F1 = Function('F_1')(x,t)
F2 = Function('F_2')(x,t)

test = diff(F1,x,2)*20*Integral(F2,t)*Integral(F1,t)*F1**2
```

I want a way to show:

```
[F1(x,t), F2(x,t), F1(x,t), F1(x,t),F1(x,t)]
```

or at least:

```
[F1(x,t), F2(x,t), F1(x,t), F1(x,t)**2]
```

without having to go into each argument branch if possible.

Edit:

I found that you can use:

```
test.count(F1)
```

Still doesn't take into account exponentials

Edit:

As Davide_sd posted, using:

```
t = test.find(lambda t: t.is_Pow and t.base == f)
```

is able to find any exponentials with a base that contains one of the free symbolic functions.

However, if the expression is of the form:

```
test = diff(F1,x,2)*20*Integral(F2,t)*Integral(F1,t)*(diff(F1,t))**2
```

This form would be better suited:

```
powterm = list(test.find(lambda t: t.is_Pow and t.base.has(f)))
```

Where you can put the `set` into a `list` and then you can check whether the list is empty:

`if(len(powterm) != 0):`

And find the actual exponential power term to see how many times the function is in this term:

```
powexp = powterm[0].exp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFunction can be used to in pattern matching operations. For example:

```
w = WildFunction("w")
funcs = test.find(w)
print(funcs)
# {F_2(x, t), F_1(x, t)}
```

Then you loop over them to find the statistics you are looking for. For example:

```
for f in funcs:
    t = test.find(lambda t: t.is_Pow and t.base == f)
    print(f, test.count(f), t)
# F_2(x, t) 1 set()
# F_1(x, t) 3 {F_1(x, t)**2}
```

Comment: This worked. Only issue is that if the problem involves something like in my edit